# Nodejs express server cant parse request Cookies from https website

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a API , and I had to allow access to https origins . Node js Express server is in http and it cant parse cookies from https website , but can on http website .

**NodeJS index.js Configs**

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    "Content-Type": "*",
    //TODO : make a array list of allowed origins
    origin: ["https://localhost:3002", "http://localhost:3003", "http://localhost:3002"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

**Axios Config on** - this use to make request to above server , and this is a https website

```
export const baseURL = "http://localhost:3001/api";

export const API = Axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  withCredentials: true
});
```

**when logging `req.cookies` on server**

from http website - `{id:1}`

from https website - `[Object: null prototype] {}`